# What is the grammatical structure of “is in large measure hereditary”?

Tags: parsing

I saw the below sentence from LSAT and I can't parse out the grammar of the first clause.

> Fur color is in large measure hereditary, for black cats are more likely than others to have black kittens.

According to the MW dictionary, "hereditary" is an adjective; how come an adjective can follow a noun and modifies it at the same time?

Please help explain this sentence.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's divide this sentence up a little.

> Fur colour is hereditary

This is the same as saying

> The cat is black

We can add an adverb in front of an adjective:

> Fur colour is **usually** hereditary

We can make an [adverb phrase](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/adverb-phrases) in various ways: one way is to start with a preposition

> **under** normal circumstances
> **to** some extent
> **from** my perspective
> **in** large measure

So, we can put this adverb phrase into your sentence

> Fur colour is **in large measure** hereditary

**in large measure** is an adverbal phrase of degree, and is a somewhat formal way of saying **to a great extent**... similar to **mostly**.

Check the examples in the [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/measure) for **measure** with the noun meaning **amount**.